# Java file.exists() Errors

Tags: java, io, save, jfilechooser

I am currently working on a "Notepad - type" file for my Object-Oriented Java class. I've got most of the program done - however I am stuck on the following issue:

When the program tries to save a file, it is supposed to first check for a files existence, obviously if the file exists the program will prompt the user for permission to overwrite the existing copy of the file [The overwrite prompt is not written yet, but it will go in the if(selectedFile.exists() == true) portion of code] - and if the file does not exist, the program will create it.

The issue I am having is that the program always **creates the file** *before* checking for the files existence. I have looked at probably 20-30+ answers to similar questions - mainly on stackoverflow, and have yet to come across the answer i need. I'm not sure if I am just "not getting it", or if I have really done something wrong..

Any answer - or hint as to where to find the answer - to this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Complete code (for the **save** portion of the program is shown below).

```
 else if(source == saveFile)//-------------------------//SAVE FILE//--------------------------   
     {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("JavaPad - Save File");
        int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser);
        String myFile;

        try
        {
           if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
           {
              myFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
              File selectedFile = new File(myFile);

              String[] lines = textArea.getText().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
              readToSave = new Scanner(lines.toString()); // CANNOT use toString() on an Array -                                        THIS WILL BE CHANGED PROPERLY?
              PrintWriter savePWriter = new PrintWriter(selectedFile);

              if(selectedFile.exists() == true)
              {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This file already exists.");
                 statusLabel.setText("File Save Aborted...");
              }
              else
              {
                 System.out.println("Creating File: " + myFile);
                 File newFile = new File(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
                 savePWriter = new PrintWriter(newFile);

                 int i = 0;
                 while(i < lines.length)
                 {
                    savePWriter.append(lines[i] + "\n");
                    System.out.println("Lines appended = " + i);
                    i++;                  
                 }
                 savePWriter.flush();
                 savePWriter.close();
                 statusLabel.setText("File Saved.");
              } 
           }
           else
           {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Save has been canceled.");
           }
        }
        catch(IOException IOSaveError)
        {
           System.out.println(IOSaveError);
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `new PrintWriter(selectedFile)`, which creates the file, right before you check whether `selectedFile` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create the `PrintWriter` before checking if the file exists. The `PrintWriter` is what causes the file to be written to.

Answer (score 0):

You do:

```
 myFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getName();
 File selectedFile = new File(myFile);
 PrintWriter savePWriter = new PrintWriter(selectedFile); // Creates File! Probably unwanted.
 if(selectedFile.exists() == true) // always true because of the line above
```

By the way, your code is far too complicated. Instead of having the variables `selectedFile` and `newFile`, which both are newly created File objects, you could simply use the File object returned by the dialog: `newFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile()`.

```
if(selectedFile.exists() == true)
```

can be simplified to

```
if (selectedFile.exists())
```

I recommend to do I/O using try-with-resources whenever possible:

```
try (final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(selectedFile)) {
    // Use writer
}
```

This helps with accidentally forgetting to close streams.